# 400 bad request error when exact POST in docs for refresh_token with Google OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I believe I am running the exact POST request in the OAuth docs ( with my credentials ), but I'm getting a 400 error. I was getting a 404 error, but then reset my client_secret and started using the new client_secret and am now getting a bad request error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    data:{
    'code':getParameterByName('code'),
        'client_id':'',
        'client_secret':'',
        'redirect_uri':encodeURI(url+'?mail=tokened'),
        'grant_type':'authorization_code'
    },
    dataType:'json',
    method:'POST',
    success:function(response){console.log(response);}});
```

Answer (score 8):

Most probably the `redirect_uri` value that you send is off; it should be **exactly** the URL that you sent in the authorization request i.e. the redirect to the authorization endpoint earlier.

Comment: It's not that, I tried changing to a URL I know is valid and something is tripping it up before that

Comment: yes after replacing redirect_uri same as authorization code request solved my issue of bad request

Comment: Great answer! It was absolute not clear that the `redirect_uri` must match the one from previous request. So, not any of your redirect URI set for this client, but exactly one which was used in previous request to that page.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long shot, but according to the HTTP/REST example available at [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) (section *Handling the OAuth 2.0 server response*) you should be sending the payload with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON.

I've seen other OAuth implementations accepting JSON payload besides the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mentioned in the specification, but maybe Google implementation is more strict.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I thought about that and was hoping that would fix it, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it works fine if you have a valid Authorization Code and fill the Client ID, Secret and Redirect URI accordingly. In your snippet client_id and client_secret are set to empty string and this may be why it's not working.
Google OAuth endpoints return nice error messages with the Bad Request responses and can help you discover what is wrong with the parameters you sent.

Answer (score 0):

your grant_type needs to be different than 'authorization_code'. You are having issues while getting tokens.
try grant_type=refresh_token

Answer (score 0):

Redirect **URL** in `.env` file should be the same **URL** in google developer account and also check the redirect url in your route `web.php`